# Spring Boot reads JWT token that shouldnt be sent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm facing a strange problem. The database is empty. There are no users. Of course I'm developing and I think my JWTToken is stored in the `localStorage` (I know that's not good and will be changed).

The httpOptions of the request below:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
};
```

Angular sends the request to Spring Boot with this method:

```js
  login(credentials) {
     console.log(httpOptions);
     return this.http
       .post<AuthenticationResponseData>(
         SIGNIN_API,
         {
           username: credentials.username,
           password: credentials.password,
         },
         httpOptions
       )
       .pipe(
         tap((resData) => {
           this.handleAuthentication(
             resData.userId,
             resData.username,
             resData.email,
             resData.accessToken
           );
         })
       );
   }
```

Nothing special to see here. The error occurs in the AuthTokenFilter in Spring Boot:

```java
 public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

     @Autowired
     private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

     @Autowired
     private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

     @Override
     protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
             throws ServletException, IOException {
         try {
             String jwt = parseJwt(request);
             if (jwt != null && jwtUtil.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                 String username = jwtUtil.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                 UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                         userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                 authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
         }

         filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
     }
...
 }
```

Somehow Spring Boot gets a JWTToken from the `HttpServletRequest`. It will always give me the the error

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User Not Found with username: DemoUser
```

No matter what I put into the login mask. This credentials are right but I need to prevent that a JWTToken is sent with the loginRequest. Where does it come from?

Comment: You just have old JWT token stored in local storage, i guess.  This token is passed as 'Bearer' HTTP Header to backend, where your code parses it and extracts username.

Comment: @AlexChernyshev yes I think the same but how can I prevent that this token is sent when I use the login() method in Angular? Because there are many possible scenarios where somebody could login with another user and would get this error. Just as an example

Comment: The login method should receive a new JWT token from backend on successful authentication and remove previous from browser's storage. But JWT is stateless by design, so everyone who can provide valid JWT header to backend will have access. Steal JWT = gain access, sad truth.

Comment: It also works to login. But this is an error that occurs even if you login correct with a new account. But I guess it's not so tragic like I thought. Because it happened after a full wipe of the database. So no normal scenario. But still it could happen when somebody deletes the account on another PC and the token would still exist. I mean this exception does not make problems but an exception is still an exception.

Comment: 'It also works to login' then this is wrong - 'login' method should be outside of user's session scope at all. 'somebody deletes the account on another PC and the token would still exist' - its common practice to check account presence and validity  in database as part of JWT validation process,

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If a token exists the token will be sent to backend and it checks would you can see in my question. But then it will check the given username and password and just login. I found in Angular ne httpInterceptor which is the reason that the token is sent.

Comment: If exactly: Angular's HTTP interceptor should be excluded from call to 'login' method, because your filter operates earlier than 'login' handler. Got it ?

Comment: Yep but I need to figure out how. I will have to google. But thanks anyway @AlexChernyshev

Comment: Im not sure if I get it quite right - but sounds like you dont want the JWT token to be sent on the requests. But per default, angular is 'smart' and appends any tokens / cookies related to authentication and stuff to your requests. Makes it quite easy to implement. You just need to replace angulars default behaviour on the login process like @AlexChernyshev said - implement a custom interceptor which does not append the jwt / bearer token to ur request. Its angulars default behaviour to do so.